# ruby on rails undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

```
sharvil@sharvil:~/railstut/blog$ rails c

Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.1)
2.2.2 :001 > q=Question.all

  Question Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `questions`.* FROM `questions`
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Question questions_id: 1, question: "What is this", almuni_almuni_id: 1, category_category_id: 1>]> 

2.2.2 :002 > q

 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Question questions_id: 1, question: "What is this", almuni_almuni_id: 1, category_category_id: 1>]> 

2.2.2 :003 > q.question

NoMethodError: undefined method `question' for #<Question::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x000000045dc178>
    from /home/sharvil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:136:in `method_missing'
```

I am getting a error in accessing q.questions .. question is column in table.

pls help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do - `q.first.question`. Your `q` is a collection of *questions* not an instance of `Question`. And you called `question` method on the collection of questions, that's why you got the error.

Answer (score 0):

In your case **q** is question collection

```
q.each do |que|
  puts que.question
end
```